# What topic in mathematics covers the properties of open and closed geometric shapes?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

What topic or branch of mathematics should I study if I want to study all about shapes like:

1. Line segment
2. Line, the slope of a line
3. Curves -- arc, circle, etc.
4. Ellipse
5. Hyperbola
6. Parabola
7. Parametric curves
8. Bezier curves
9. Rectangle, triangles, parallelogram, trapezium, rhombus, etc.
10. 3d shapes like cylinder, cone, sphere, hemisphere, etc.

Sorry, when I was in school, I was very good at all this and I used to even teach all this to younger students, but now I have forgotten it almost completely. But I think if I study a little bit, a lot of it will return very quickly.

What should I type in google if I want to study these things? Are they all a part of a single branch of maths? Is that *linear algebra* or something else? Sorry I am so stupid in maths just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should study [analytic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_geometry). This branch of mathematics best suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much.